# How to check whether Suhosin is installed?

Tags: php, suhosin

I'm not familiar with Suhosin (never used it) but if possible I need to check using PHP whether it is installed. This is for part of an installer that I'm writing. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To detect the Suhosin Extension use extension_loaded() no matter if it is dynamically loaded or statically compiled:

```
extension_loaded('suhosin');
```

To detect the Suhosin-Patch, check for the constant presence:

```
constant("SUHOSIN_PATCH");
```

Answer (score 7):

simply write a php file in your document root like  `<?php  phpinfo(); ?>`
it will print all the information related to php installation just find for the "suhosin" block in it is installed on your server you can find the block with all the values set for it.

Comment: suhosin show up in php info if it was included as PHP extension

Answer (score 3):

```
extension_loaded('suhosin');
```

PHP docs for [`extension_loaded`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php).

If the extension doesn't load, it may still be available through [`dl`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php):

```
if (!extension_loaded('suhosin')) {
    if (!dl('suhosin.so')) {
        // Extension not loaded.
        return false;
    }
}

// Extension loaded.
return true;
```

Comment: This will not work if you compiled suhosin as a part of your PHP interpreter. Installing as the extension in not the only way of installation. http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/how_to_install_or_upgrade.html

Comment: @netme, I wasn't aware of this, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You can test if a configuration open is set for Suhosin:

```
$isSuhosinInstalled = ini_get('suhosin.session.max_id_length') !== '';
```

Comment: This will not work on all systems with Suhosin installed too. On many systems Suhosin is unconfigured by default. I tried on my 2 hostings, on both variables were not initialized.

Comment: @netme, Odd; I thought PHP filled in the default value if it was missing from the actual configuration files.  Oh well.