# ini_set("memory_limit") in PHP 5.3.3 is not working at all

Tags: php, memory, apache2, debian

I had this working before :

```
echo ini_get("memory_limit")."\n";
ini_set("memory_limit","256M");
echo ini_get("memory_limit")."\n";
```

That would input this :

```
32M
256M
```

on a php script executed by command line.
I updated from 5.2 to 5.3, and from now, this directive is not working at all  : this gives me :

```
32M
32M
```

and then make my script fail with a fatal Error...

I checked the php documentation, and googled it, and I didn't find anywhere that "memory_limit" had been deprecated.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: could try: php_value memory_limit 256M to your .htaccess

Comment: use php.ini for that, this is was an unfortunate in my case .

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Most likely your sushosin updated, which changed the default of suhosin.memory_limit from disabled to 0 (which won't allow any updates to memory_limit).

On Debian, change /etc/php5/conf.d/suhosin.ini

> ;suhosin.memory_limit = 0

to

> suhosin.memory_limit = 2G

Or whichever value you are comfortable with. You can find the changelog of Sushosin at [http://www.hardened-php.net/hphp/changelog.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20190324122444/http://www.hardened-php.net/hphp/changelog.html), which says:

> Changed the way the memory_limit protection is implemented

Comment: very helpful! The suhosin docs for this setting indicate that it's an integer and don't clearly communicate that you can use the (MG) suffixes; thus I was thrown off until I read this.

Answer (score 32):

Here's a list of things that are worth checking:

**Is Suhosin installed?**

- [How to check whether Suhosin is installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383916/how-to-check-whether-suhosin-is-installed)

**ini_set**

- The format is important

  `ini_set('memory_limit', '512');      // DIDN'T WORK
  ini_set('memory_limit', '512MB');    // DIDN'T WORK
  ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');     // OK - 512MB
  ini_set('memory_limit', 512000000);  // OK - 512MB`

> When an integer is used, the value is measured in bytes. Shorthand
>   notation, as described in this [FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes), may also be used.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

- Has php_admin_value been used in .htaccess or virtualhost files?

> Sets the value of the specified directive. This can not be used in
>   .htaccess files. Any directive type set with php_admin_value can not
>   be overridden by .htaccess or ini_set(). To clear a previously set
>   value use none as the value.

http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Comment: `ini_set('memory_limit', '512');` actually works, it just set the memory limit to 512B

Answer (score 25):

If you have the suhosin extension enabled, it can prevent scripts from setting the memory limit beyond what it started with or some defined cap.

http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.memory_limit

Answer (score 4):

Works for me, has nothing to do with PHP 5.3. Just like many such options it cannot be overriden via `ini_set()` when safe_mode is enabled. Check your updated `php.ini` (and better yet: change the memory_limit there too).

Comment: very little sucks more than php safe_mode()

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu 10.04 comes with the Suhosin patch only, which does not give you configuration options. But you can install php5-suhosin to solve this:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install php5-suhosin
```

Now you can edit /etc/php5/conf.d/suhosin.ini and set:

```
suhosin.memory_limit = 1G
```

Then using ini_set will work in a script:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's do a test with 2 examples:

```
    <?php    
    $memory = (int)ini_get("memory_limit"); // Display your current value in php.ini (for example: 64M)
    echo "original memory: ".$memory."<br>";
    ini_set('memory_limit','128M'); // Try to override the memory limit for this script
    echo "new memory:".$memory;
    }
    // Will display:
    // original memory: 64
    // new memory: 64
    ?>
```

The above example doesn't work for overriding the memory_limit value.
But This will work:

```
    <?php
    $memory = (int)ini_get("memory_limit"); // get the current value
    ini_set('memory_limit','128'); // override the value
    echo "original memory: ".$memory."<br>"; // echo the original value
    $new_memory = (int)ini_get("memory_limit"); // get the new value
    echo "new memory: ".$new_memory;  // echo the new value
    // Will display:
    // original memory: 64
    // new memory: 128
    ?>
```

You have to place the `ini_set('memory_limit','128M');` at the **top of the file** or **at least before any echo**.

As for me, **suhosin** wasn't the solution because it doesn't even appear in my phpinfo(), but this worked:

```
    <?php
    ini_set('memory_limit','2048M'); // set at the top of the file
    (...)
    ?>
```

Comment: You have a flaw in your code, thus your conclusion is wrong!

Comment: @DUzun can you explain where is the "flaw" in my code ? (i don't know what is a "flaw", i'm not native English speaker). An explaination of your point, for my code which works (i've tested it, and i use it), would be better than just a -1. Thx

Comment: @DUzun i have modified the example that i tested again with a blank php file. My conclusion is a bit different but my previous solution is still working.