# PHP memory_limit locked to 256MB?

Tags: php

I am trying to set memory_limit to 512M, but it's locekd to 256M.

```
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
ini_get('memory_limit');    //> Returns: 256M
```

I have full control on my server. (it's a dedicated)

Please note that everything under 512M works.

```
ini_set('memory_limit','16M');
ini_get('memory_limit');    //> Returns: 16M
```

### Solution

I found out why. in php.ini I had `memory_limit = 256M`. Maybe this is considered as an upper limit

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061917/ini-setmemory-limit-in-php-5-3-3-is-not-working-at-all

Comment: Did you try raising it in php.ini as well? Or is this just a one-off thing where you want to grant only a specific script more memory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

3 possibles I can think of / find:

> Prior to PHP 5.2.1, in order to use this directive it had to be
>   enabled at compile time by using --enable-memory-limit in the
>   configure line.

OR

The issue detailed here: [ini_set("memory_limit") in PHP 5.3.3 is not working at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061917/ini-setmemory-limit-in-php-5-3-3-is-not-working-at-all)

OR

ini_set is disabled

Comment: Looks like the second one is the most probable.

Comment: Which version of PHP are you running?

Comment: I found in my php.ini memory_limit = 256M. That was locking to that value. I have PHP `5.3.3-7`

Answer (score 4):

You can also try to change the memory_limit using either a php.ini or .htaccess file

php.ini

```
memory_limit = 512M;
```

.htaccess

```
php_value memory_limit 512M
```

Comment: @Ing - sorry I had mixed up my variables, so let me update my answer

Answer (score 3):

A bit late in the day but editing the php.ini file didn't work for php 7.1 using Mac OS 10.11.6. I still kept on getting the 'PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of....' which from its value showed the memory setting was not updating after starting apache.

So instead of editing the file.

```
/usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini
```

I found changing the following file fixed this issue.

```
/usr/local/php5/php.d/99-liip-developer.ini
```

This file was actually replacing the values set in the initial php.ini file. Again making the following changes to the line...

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

to

```
memory_limit = 1024M
```

And restarting apache.

```
sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart
```

Comment: Please edit your answer with more details about to your solution. This is a path file, nothing explicitly related to memory.

Comment: Saved me hours. Thanks!

Comment: It does solve the problem Georges, that is the correct path for the memory_limit in some cases, at least in mine. Thanks Paul !!

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that on my Mac (OS X El Capitan) and the new PHP 7.0.0, I cannot change memory_limit via php.ini

But I can change it via /etc/apache2/httpd.conf by adding the line in the end:

*php_value memory_limit 1024M*

and restarting apache server:

*sudo apachectl restart*

And it is the correct php.ini , I can change other settings via it.

Comment: Good shout - however it should be noted that this will not change the *master* php value, and instead changes the *local* value for each site (as per the `.htaccess` or `ini_set` solutions)

Answer (score 0):

You could check in your php.ini config file at the directive called "disable_functions". Check if ini_set is disabled.

Also if safe_mode is enabled such option may not be overriden.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why. in php.ini I had `memory_limit = 256M`. Maybe this is considered as an upper limit.

I rised it to my need.