# Trouble with ini_set("memory_limit") in php 5.3

Tags: php, memory

I am attempting to use `ini_set("memory_limit", "256M");` to set the memory limit to 256M for my script, but it doesn't seem to work.
`echo ini_get("memory_limit");`
gives me `128M` which is the default.
Using `ini_set` to change the max execution time does when tested the same way.

Having already found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061917/ini-setmemory-limit-in-php-5-3-3-is-not-working-at-all) I checked the suhosin.ini and php.ini files. Suhosin caps it at 2048M though php.ini limits that to 512.
I am not running into either of those caps, and there is another script in the same directory running with a memory limit of 512MB, so there isn't anything in the .htaccess. Is there somewhere else I should be checking?

Comment: `ini_set("memory_limit", "256M"); var_dump(ini_get('memory_limit'));` What does that say?

Comment: Forgot to put that in, thanks.