# Laravel FatalErrorException: Out of memory

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

I am trying to export my **zip** file but I get the error:

```
Fatal Error Exception in ProjectFinding.php line 387:
Out of memory (allocated 382468096) (tried to allocate 1346263 bytes)
```

php.ini `set memory_limit=2048M`. Is there something wrong?
Please tell me why this error due **error** in code or **memory** and how to fix this error?

It shows error in this line

```
 $zip->addFromString($nfile[1], file_get_contents($file));
```

Comment: Did you restart/reload the PHP/Apache service after changing the ini file?

Comment: Please show your code, we can't help otherwise. Also, try outputting `phpinfo()` and find your `memory_limit` value in there to confirm it is what you think it is.

Comment: check this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061917/ini-setmemory-limit-in-php-5-3-3-is-not-working-at-all

Comment: Please share your code. And you've to check the memory limit.

Comment: You should check if you have an infinite loop or an infinite recursion in your code, I used to get these errors when I had them.

Answer (score -1):

```
public function excel_exports($input, $p_id) {
        $find = new Project();
        $tmp_name = time();
        $path = storage_path("files/" . $p_id);
        if (!is_dir($path)) {
            umask(0);
            mkdir($path, 0777, true);
            chmod($path, 0777);
        }

        $project = new Project();
        $prodata = $project->getById($p_id);
        $zipfile = $prodata->id.'.zip';
        $excelname = $prodata->id;
        $data = $findingObj->getAll($p_id);
        $colspan = 1;
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            $this->_saveDocumentsFiles($row);
            $doc_cc = 0;
            foreach ($row->document as $doc) {
                $doc_cc = $doc_cc + $doc->doc_files->count();
            }
            if ($doc_cc > $colspan) {
                $colspan = $doc_cc;
            }
        }
        Excel::create($excelname, function($excel) use ($data, $colspan) {
            $excel->sheet('projectfinding', function($sheet) use ($data, $colspan) {
                $sheet->loadView('admin.project.finding.excel_file_exports')->with(["targetRow" => 5, "targetCol" => "A", "targetView" => "admin.project.finding.excel_pdf", 'data' => $data, 'colspan' => $colspan]);
            });
        })->save('xls', $path, false);
        $source = storage_path('files');
        $this->zip($source, $zipfile);
        header("Content-type: application/zip");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$zipfile");
        readfile($zipfile);
        unlink(public_path($zipfile));
        $rmpath = storage_path("files/" . $p_id);
        $this->_rrmdir($rmpath);
        return true;
    }

in this code i simply change p_id with id it will show error in $path and $rmpath
```