# ini_set('memory_limit', ...) doesn't work and returns false; can't figure out why

Tags: php, apache, php-ini

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M'); // Returns false; memory_limit unchanged
```

I wasn't able to find a list of things that can cause this. So far I checked:

- Safe mode: disabled
- disable_functions: Empty
- php_admin_value: None that I could find (is there a way to know for sure?)

I ran out of ideas! `ini_set` works correctly with other parameters (such as "display_errors")

Comment: which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Does it fail for any directive passed to `ini_set()` or just `memory_limit`?  Does any value for `memory_limit` fail, or just `128M`?  How are you verifying that the value is unchanged?  I have noticed this behavior on a couple of servers over here as well, so I am very interested to see if we are experiencing the same problem.

Comment: are you using a shared hosting platform or is this a machine you setup/configured yourself?

Comment: @James: I am using PHP Version 5.2.6-1+lenny9.

Comment: @Phoenix: it fails only with memory_limit. I verify that the value is unchanged by calling ini_get.

Comment: @James question 2: This is a dedicated server our network administrator set up. This is our dev server where we test our code; on the live servers, ini_set works correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's not the PHP version problem posted already try checking that there's nothing on the machine preventing your from raising this limit.

[How to check whether Suhosin is installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383916/how-to-check-whether-suhosin-is-installed)

edit (after establishing that Suhosin is installed):

Config details are here: http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html
I suspect there'll be a file in `/etc/php.d/` that you can edit to increase the memory limit bounds. The config variable you need to edit is: [suhosin.memory_limit](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.memory_limit)

Comment: Bingo! This server is protected with the Suhosin Patch 0.9.10.. Now what is it? I'll try to google it and see if it's the problem or not

Comment: Well it's probably this, but I can't find a setting option that says "never go higher than 64M".. Do you know where it may be configured? Or it works this way by default? In any case I opened a ticket for our network admin hopefully he'll be able to sort this out

Comment: ok, our network admin changed the sushosin option and now it works. ty

Answer (score 1):

[The manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) says :

> Prior to PHP 5.2.1, in order to use
>   this directive it had to be enabled at
>   compile time by using
>   --enable-memory-limit in the configure line

That might be the cause of your problem.

Comment: We use: PHP Version 5.2.6-1+lenny9, so "unfortunately" it's not the problem =(