# php.ini changes, but not effective on Ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, apache2

I want change the limit of PHP upload file's size

And this is some information of the output my [phpinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php):

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path    /etc/php5/apache2
Loaded Configuration File    /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

And this is the content of my *php.ini* file:

```
upload_max_filesize = 50M
post_max_size = 50M
memory_limit = 128M
```

Then I restart Apache 2, but the phpinfo shown is still:

```
upload_max_filesize    2M
```

Comment: Did you install them yourself or use a package to get them?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have solved my question.

There is a syntax error in *php.ini* in line 109, so the next all syntax does not execute.

Comment: What do you mean by *"the next all syntax does not execute"* (seem incomprehensible)?  Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11673121/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 11):

There is a good chance you didn't have permissions to modify the *php.ini* file. If you just browse to it via a normal folder window and click it [Gedit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gedit) (or whatever your default text editor is) won't be able to open it with write permissions.

You should be able to get away by `sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` (then your password at the prompt) and then changing the variables. Then be sure to *write out* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>) or make sure you confirm the save on exit.

Answer (score 10):

For anyone wondering why the php.ini modification is not applied even after all directives are fine and restarting the apache on ubuntu, try restarting apache with sudo

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem and this solve it
I have foound php.ini inside folder /etc/php5/cli/php.ini I make changes to it

### and restart apache sudo apache2ctl restart

I have already change /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and restart apache by using sudo service apache2 restart but symfony doesn't see changes

I write it , it may help anyone

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I solved this issue on Ubuntu after about three hours of debugging (PHP 7)

Steps

1. Run [phpinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) function and observe where the loaded PHP configuration file (*php.ini*) is

   [image]
2. 'cd' into that directory and update it to the new values
3. Reboot your server
4. It works!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect a lot of these problems are being experienced because [FastCGI Process Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Installation_and_configuration) (php-fpm) is now used by default on a lot of new Apache installations. After making the changes, you need to restart the fast CGI daemon, not *httpd*.

See *[When php.ini appears to be ignored](https://www.citylinux.com/?topic=notes/php.ini.html)*

Answer (score 0):

I use over ubuntu 14.10 the command:

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem but then found that root permission is needed to edit php.ini file so just opened the terminal and wrote the following

```
gksudo gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

and it perfectly worked!!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't rename the `php.ini` file，use the `cp php.ini-production php.ini`, and then `/etc/init.d/apache2 reload`, else just reload or restart.