# Laravel Dropzone TokenMismatchException for Large Files

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, dropzone.js

I have a Laravel application and a form with dropzone. 
Normally ,  it works well. But when i try to upload large files ( 50M - 60 M), I get this error `TokenMismatchException`.

I'm using this code to send token :

```
formData.append("_token", $('[name=_token]').val());
```

I also changed all php.ini settings:

- `max_upload_size`
- `set_time_limit(0);`
- `memory_limit`
- `post_max_size`
- `max_input_time`

As said above, it's working for small files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue. It's because of `php.ini` file. I edited and saved `php.ini` but it didn't effect the output of `phpinfo();` function. Output was showing old values.
Check this link for solution :

[Changes to upload_max_filesize in Ubunutu php.ini will not take effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327409/changes-to-upload-max-filesize-in-ubunutu-php-ini-will-not-take-effect)

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed all the php settings, that should not be an issue. However, if this is being done over AJAX, then appending a `_token` to the request is messy and hacky. Instead, set the `{{ csrf_token }}` as your request header. More specifically, set it on the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header, since Laravel checks for that in the middleware.