# php ini setting upload_max_filesize not working

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-16.04

I need to change upload limit to 2GB  on php 7.2 Ubuntu 16.04.

As a first step,  when I check `/etc/php/7.2` folder I can see `cli` and 
`fpm` folders.

So to make sure the ini location I have print the php info using

```
 echo phpinfo()
```

And I got the output

```
Server API                         :   FPM/FastCGI
Virtual Directory Support          :   disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path  :   /etc/php/7.2/fpm
Loaded Configuration File          :   /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini
```

And I have edited `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini` with

`upload_max_filesize = 2048M`

And restarted the apache  but  using phpinfo() still it print

```
  upload_max_filesize   2M
```

So I have tried with command  `php -i | grep -i "loaded configuration file"` but it print different configuration file,

```
 Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
```

On this file also I have changed upload_max_filesize to 2048 and restarted the Apache and still the result is same.

What could be the problem, any help will appreciated.

Comment: can you try using 2G instead of 2048M ? just a try, but i don't think it's relevant.

Comment: Anyway, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37381522/php-7-php-ini-upload-max-filesize-not-working

Comment: check post_max_size, upload_max_filesize

Answer (score 6):

I got the problem resolved by the answer here [Changes to upload_max_filesize in Ubuntu php.ini will not take effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327409/changes-to-upload-max-filesize-in-ubuntu-php-ini-will-not-take-effect/19997441#19997441).

Instead of restarting the apache I have to restart the php using

```
sudo service php7.2-fpm restart
```

Comment: After struggling for 2weeks, finally this helped. Thank you so much man.

Answer (score 3):

You should also change in php.ini:
post_max_size=2Gb

Answer (score 1):

first at all you should remove all older php version on your ubuntu.
what is your cli php version?
are you sure that you find correctly php.ini location?
please run this command " locate php.ini "

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes due to error in php.ini files the configuration files are not loaded after that specific error line. In that case you have to thoroughly check the php.ini file and fix the errors.

Alternatively you can download fresh php.ini files for your php version and replace your existing file with the new one.

After making changes in the new file restart your server using `service apache2 restart` .

Answer (score 0):

If changing `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini` and `/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini` still does not work out, try changing `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini`. Please note that you might have to restart the apache2 server using `sudo service apache2 restart`. (This solution is tested on server with Ubuntu installed. )

Answer (score 0):

After editing /etc/php/8.2/fpm/php.ini -> sudo service php8.2-fpm restart -> sudo service apache2 restart. Works for me.