# PHP ignoring (mostly?) addtional .ini files

Tags: php, homebrew, ini, pecl

I just upgraded PHP from 7.2 to 7.3 using Homebrew on my Mac. apcu and xdebug were (re)installed with pecl. `phpinfo()` outputs that the "additional" ini files where I have some custom config for the extensions are being parsed; however, none of the configs from those files are being used. *E.g.*, I have set `xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1500` in the supposedly parsed xdebug.ini file, but it's still set at the default 256.

Both .ini files begin with `extension="xxx.so"`, and I've searched for other references to the extensions, but come up empty. (There's no reference, *e.g.*, to either extension in the base php.ini file.) I've also tested commenting out those refs, and the extensions are not loaded when that is done. So, at this point, I'm assuming they're being loaded because of the references in those files, but nothing else there is being used. Both files were copied unchanged from the previous version, where they worked just fine.

I've restarted PHP, Apache, and even rebooted the machine, all to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out after continued searching, and finding this posted answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61213555/5637730

Apparently, the hash (#)-prefixed comments which weren't interferring with anything in my previous php installations, are no longer allowed. This is odd to me as they've apparently been deprecated since 5.3, and eliminated as of 7.0 (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php#configuration.file.changelog), but I've only been using xdebug since maybe 5.6, have never seen a warning, nor had any issue in 7.2. And, in fact, I'm running 7.3 on another machine, where again, the hash comments are working like comments should.

At any rate, replacing my hashes with semicolons (;) resolved my issue.