# Find the correct php.ini file

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

I am currently trying to locate the correct *php.ini* file to edit it and restart Apache, so the changes will take place and I'm stumped.

What I have done...

I have found three different *php.ini* files (I don’t have any idea why there are three). This is how I found the files: `sudo find / -name php.ini`. It resulted in the following....

```
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini
```

I also did....

```
sudo php -i | grep 'Configuration File'
```

This showed....

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

I changed all of them (just to be sure) to the settings I wanted.

I restarted Apache using:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

The results...

```
* Restarting web server apache2
```

I reloaded the page and it showed that the *php.ini* file was not
updated.

I know this because I used

```
echo ini_get('post_max_size');
```

Which was supposed to be changed to 20M, but it was still only 2M.

I tried rebooting my computer thinking maybe that would legit stop the Apache server and reload the php.ini file with the correct setting, but alas that attempt also failed.

Is there any chance there could be another *php.ini* file that could be interfering?

---

A better, more helpful for other users answer can be found here:
*[Find the correct php.ini file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356968/find-the-correct-php-ini-file)*

Comment: Have you changed value & Checked using ini_get() function in all php.ini files one by one?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check different php.ini files using the ini_get() function, but yes I have done ** echo ini_get('post_max_size'); ** . Which prints the default value (which should have been changed to 20)

Comment: Have you edited the `php.ini` file which is shown in the webpage by `phpinfo()`. You must do this by `sudo`.

Comment: Find `post_max_size` in the phpinfo page, is it still `2M` after you changed the value in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`? Have you set the value in the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @srain Yes it is still the same (as if I had not changed a thing) and no, I don't even have .htaccess file.

Comment: I have found a possible solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11673121/1653716. Saying basically they had a syntax error in their php.ini file which prevented apache from loading the other non-default values. Do you know if there is an easy way of checking the php.ini for syntax errors?

Comment: @Michael What I meant was edit only 1 php.ini file one time & see the output using ** echo ini_get('post_max_size'); ** If you're not seeing any change, Revert back to old value, edit 2nd php.ini file, see the output & so on..If none of the file edits shows the change you expected, It does mean (I think) file changes are not being updated Or have you already tried all these?

Comment: Please avoid crossposting: http://askubuntu.com/questions/356968/find-the-correct-php-ini-file.

Comment: I have read on Stack Exchange Meta that cross-posting is not necessarily a bad thing.  It is increasingly more likely that questions will be ontopic at multiple sites as the number of SE sites increases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this was very simple. Somewhere in my *php.ini* file I had a syntax error (or an error of some kind).

To fix this, I downloaded the latest *php.ini* file from http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob_plain;f=php.ini-production;hb=HEAD and then changed the values for upload_max_filesize and post_max_size, restarted Apache, reloaded my php_info() and everything was working as expected!

Answer (score 20):

As Apache calls PHP by `mod_php`, the configuration information is not the same with that in command line:

Create a file named `index.php` at the root directory, with the code below in it:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
```

then open it in your browser: `/index.php`.

Then you will see all the configuration information.

Answer (score 3):

Create a PHP file and put the following code in it:

```
phpinfo();
```

Open the file in your browser and find loaded configuration file. Presto.

Comment: I have done this already (first thing I did actually). The results said this "/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini" was the loaded configuration file. I edited it, restarted apache, and still found that the configuration did not change.