# php.ini ignores some settings

Tags: php, apache, lamp

Using LAMP server with Ubuntu I an trying to increase the following:

- upload_max_filesize
- post_max_size
- session.gc_maxlifetime

By using `phpinfo()` I checked the basics:

- Configuration File (php.ini) Path: `/etc/php5/apache2`
- Loaded Configuration File: `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

If I change `upload_max_filesize` from 2M to 3M and restart Apache `phpinfo()` still shows 2M.
However if I change **precision** or **output_buffering** the new value is displayed by `phpinfo()`.

Why does php ignores some of my settings? How shall I tackle this?

Comment: are you sure you aren't overwriting those settings in your .htaccess?

Comment: @giorgio, I do not use .htaccess file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of searching I found a hint [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662295/php-ini-changes-but-not-effective-in-ubuntu).

When I wanted to adjust the error reporting level I copied what I found on php.net to my php.ini file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

This works if you are using it in a PHP script, but not in the .ini file.

The correct format for configuration is:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

The tricky bit is that PHP will stop if there is a syntax error and settings after the error will not be executed.

Hope my saga will help others.