# How can I know which 'php.ini' file is used?

Tags: php, php-ini

I search the path where the *php.ini* file is located in our Linux Ubuntu server, and I found many *php.ini* files when executing the command `find / -name php.ini`. So how can I know exactly from a PHP script web page where the php.ini is located?

Comment: Use the documentation (http://php.net/info) and `php --help` on the command line.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can use [php_ini_loaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php).

Taken from *php.net*:

```
$inipath = php_ini_loaded_file();
if ($inipath) {
    echo 'Loaded php.ini: ' . $inipath;
} else {
    echo 'A php.ini file is not loaded';
}
```

You may also want to check [php_ini_scanned_files()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-scanned-files.php).

Also, you should note that if you run a PHP script from CLI, it's possible that a different `php.ini` file will be used than if a server (e.g., nginx or Apache) runs it.

Other options:

- `php -i|grep 'php.ini'`
- create `info.php` that contains `<?php phpinfo();` in the webroot, and run it in your browser

Answer (score 127):

```
php --ini
```

For the webserver-SAPIs use `phpinfo()`

Here's some sample output:

```
bash-3.2# php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/php5/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/php5/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/php5/php.d/10-extension_dir.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/20-extension-opcache.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/40-openssl.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-apcu.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-curl.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-gmp.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-imap.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-intl.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-mcrypt.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-mssql.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-pdo_pgsql.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-pgsql.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-propro.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-raphf.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-readline.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-xdebug.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-xsl.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/60-extension-pecl_http.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/99-liip-developer.ini
```

Comment: If you have conflicts (same property gets defined in multiple loaded .ini files)  Does the additional .ini files overwrite the loaded configuration file or vice versa?

Comment: Hi @LloydBanks Yes.
I wouldn't name it "conflict", because it's by design, that you can define default values and override them in some environments. When I look into my local `/etc/php/conf.d` I can find filenames like `10-sqlite.ini`. The "10" is there, because the files are loaded in lexical order. With the prefix you can control the order and therefore control which (duplicate) properties takes precedence.

Answer (score 16):

Note that the configuration loaded for PHP when it's being used in the console is different from the configuration for the web process. Most PHP installations would come with a *php.ini* file for Apache and another for CLI.

To know which configuration file is used for the console commands, use

```
php -i | grep "Configuration File"
```

To know which configuration file is used for the web processes, follow these steps

1. Create an info file (preferably in the root folder)
2. The contents of this file should be `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and search for "Configuration File"

Answer (score 6):

You have to use the PHP method `php_ini_loaded_file` (only after PHP 5.2.4)

> php_ini_loaded_file — Retrieve a path to the loaded php.ini file

PHP website example:

```
<?php
$inipath = php_ini_loaded_file();

if ($inipath) {
    echo 'Loaded php.ini: ' . $inipath;
} else {
    echo 'A php.ini file is not loaded';
}
?>
```

Source: [PHP site](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php)

Comment: @VahidFarahmand You can assume, that PHP4 is not in usage anymore.

Answer (score 6):

Just add a file like this:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

Then look for

```
Loaded Configuration File
```

You'll see the full path for the *php.ini* file.

Answer (score 3):

Create a simple page and it will be listed there!

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, "find / -name php.ini" will help get all the *php.ini* files. The one you may be editing may not be the one from which the server is drawing the command from! I found *php.ini* for three different versions of PHP on my server and I got the fix instantly then.

Comment: Re *"I got the fix instantly"*: Can you elaborate on what you did? How did you decide on which one to use?

Comment: This isn't a reliable method on many server setups where there could be many copies of the file, not all of which are being used.