# Setting size limit for uploading files in php/HTML

Tags: php, html, ubuntu, size, limit

How do i set limit for the size of the file which server will receive in php before the file gets completely uploaded?

I've changed `php.ini`:

```
upload_max_filesize = 1M
post_max_size = 1M
```

and rebooted the system.

But it doesn't do anything while the heavier file is being uploaded and exceeds the limit.

**UPD:** I figured out that even if there's no `upload.php` file, the `html` will upload the file till it's completely uploaded. How should i set size limit for html?

Comment: Maybe the wrong php.ini is being used. Follow instructions such as this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558150/how-to-know-which-php-ini-is-used/14558201

to debug which php.ini is being used. You might be modifying a php.ini for cli instead of the one that needs to be modified for your site.

Comment: @SawanVaidya I figured out that even there's no `upload.php` file, the `html` will upload the file till it's completely uploaded. How should i limit the html?