# Uncaught Error: Class 'Memcached' not found—shows in `php -i` but not in browser via phpinfo();

Tags: php, linux, centos, memcached

Running CentOS7, I installed Memcached via:

`yum install memcached libmemcached`

`php -i | grep memcached` shows:

```
/etc/php.d/50-memcached.ini
memcached
memcached support => enabled
libmemcached version => 1.0.18
memcached.compression_factor => 1.3 => 1.3
memcached.compression_threshold => 2000 => 2000
memcached.compression_type => fastlz => fastlz
memcached.default_binary_protocol => Off => Off
memcached.default_connect_timeout => 0 => 0
memcached.default_consistent_hash => Off => Off
memcached.serializer => igbinary => igbinary
memcached.sess_binary_protocol => On => On
memcached.sess_connect_timeout => 0 => 0
memcached.sess_consistent_hash => On => On
memcached.sess_consistent_hash_type => ketama => ketama
memcached.sess_lock_expire => 0 => 0
memcached.sess_lock_max_wait => not set => not set
memcached.sess_lock_retries => 5 => 5
memcached.sess_lock_wait => not set => not set
memcached.sess_lock_wait_max => 150 => 150
memcached.sess_lock_wait_min => 150 => 150
memcached.sess_locking => On => On
memcached.sess_number_of_replicas => 0 => 0
memcached.sess_persistent => Off => Off
memcached.sess_prefix => memc.sess.key. => memc.sess.key.
memcached.sess_randomize_replica_read => Off => Off
memcached.sess_remove_failed_servers => Off => Off
memcached.sess_sasl_password => no value => no value
memcached.sess_sasl_username => no value => no value
memcached.sess_server_failure_limit => 0 => 0
memcached.store_retry_count => 2 => 2
Registered save handlers => files user memcache memcached
```

However, when I run a PHP file in browser, I get the following error:
"Uncaught Error: Class 'Memcached' not found in (my path)..."

When I run `phpinfo()` in the browser, Memcached isn't loaded at all.

I have SELinux running:
`getsebool httpd_can_network_memcache
httpd_can_network_memcache --> on`

I do know that Memcached and Memcache are two different libraries, so I'm not sure if that's helping my problem at all.

My web server is nginx, and I have already tried restarting it a couple of times.

Comment: php-cli (command line) and php-fpm (nginx) use two different configuration files. The `phpinfo()` output in your browser will tell you which nginx is using. You likely have memcache enabled in the former but not the latter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to know which php.ini is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558150/how-to-know-which-php-ini-is-used)

Comment: Hmm okay, Server API: FPM/FastCGI.

phpinfo() does show that the config file is in /etc/php.ini.

When I go to that file and add: extension=memcached.so, "php -i" returns this error:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'memcached.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/memcached.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/memcached.so: undefined symbol: php_json_decode_ex), /usr/lib64/php/modules/memcached.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/memcached.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: I ran `service php-fpm restart` and now Memcached loads in phpinfo(). Thanks!