# I have changed every last PHP.ini, *.ini related or unrelated on my server for setting post_max_size to 8000M but its not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have changed every last PHP.ini, *.ini related or unrelated on my server for setting post_max_size to 8000M but its not working.But atleast 50M will do my work.I am stuck here.
restarted server after changing every php.ini 
httpd - k restart 
even stopped server and start again.

but i cant see a small change in PHP.info

tried various tricks like
 
1) php_ini
2) .htaccess
3) .user.ini 
but not getting desired result .Please help

I have dedicated server.With WHM and root access but still nothing working
CentOS release 6.8 (Final)

All the suggested answers make change in HTACESS or php.ini while  i already changed on it. more than any time.

Comment: What are you attempting to do? Do you still see the old value when you view phpinfo(), or is your upload just not working? If you're uploading a file, have you tried changing `upload_max_filesize`?

Comment: Run a `phpinfo()` and look at the first page for a line that tells you where the `php.ini` file is being loaded from

Comment: [Do a little reading](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Comment: yes i did everything , the very first thing i did is goto php_info find proper directory and edit that php.ini file

Comment: Are your changes applied or not (do you see them in phpinfo() )?

Comment: @ aynber i am still seing old value in php.ini

Comment: @Blackbam  i am still seing old value in php.in

Comment: `post_max_size` is not the only thing that can prevent an upload from working. I think you should edit your question to add more information about what you're trying to do in general, and what specific problem you're having. You've included a lot of things you've tried, which is good, but "not working" is not much to go on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP : settings memory\_limits > 1024M does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276212/php-settings-memory-limits-1024m-does-not-work)

Comment: @ExtjsCommander Its maybe not an exact duplicate as you asked for post_max_size but the answers of the other post may be sufficient?

Comment: its not php then, it's apache refusing it. google LimitRequestBody

Answer (score 1):

First create a phpinfo.php file within your web directory (ideally in the same folder where the scripts you are testing are saved) containing:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Then access this file using a browser.
Right close to the top there is a line saying:

> Loaded Configuration File         /etc/php/some/path/php.ini

Edit the loaded php.ini file as follows:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 50M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 50M
```

Your question mentions only post_max_size, but if your form accepts files you need to change upload_max_filesize too.

After that you need to restart the web sever (apache?). If you are using php-fpm then you need to restart that process. I don't know about centOS, but for ubuntu commands can be:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo service php-fpm restart
```

Reload the phpinfo file in your browser and check if both values have been updated.

Comment: hi , upload_max_filesize  and others are already working and edited before.