# PHP explode max size

Tags: php, parsing, explode

I am trying to explode file content , but it seems explode cant create array with large size of variable.

Is there any max array size for explode function?

```
$lines = explode ( "\n", $filecontent );
```

Comment: Why would you use explode against a file content, when PHP provides `file()` anyway; but just how big is this file? And the fact that you have the content in memory, and try to create an array in memory as well is going to use at least double the memory, and then some

Comment: Have a look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276212/php-settings-memory-limits-1024m-does-not-work  It might help work around your problem, although theres a finite limit on the amount of memory you can consume.

Answer (score 0):

if you want read file for line  dont use explode
you can use fread() or fgets()