# PHP memory limit changed but still can't pass PHP Settings Check

Tags: php, magento2, memory-limit

When doing the readiness check in Magento 2, PHP Settings Check has an error as shown below "Your current PHP memory limit is 128M"

[image]

I followed the solutions that they provided and changed the memory_limit to 1000M on all php.ini files, restart the server but it still does not work. 
After which, I checked back and the memory_limit and it is changed to 1000M but it still does not pass the PHP Settings Check.
Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276212/php-settings-memory-limits-1024m-does-not-work

Comment: How / Where did you change the settings? Have you tried reloading or restarting your server after the changes were made?

Comment: I have tried changing the memory limit in ht.access too but it does not work @GCRdev

Comment: I changed the memory_limit in php.ini to "memory_limit = 1000M" and yes have tried to restart the server but still not working @blokeish

Comment: it should be .htaccess  . You can try placing a new php.ini file with just that entry in the root folder of your script. Contact your service provider to see how you can override the php.ini settings.  By the way what is your OS and what is the location of your php.ini file?