# Does PHP set memory limits on arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, xdebug, suhosin

I have a weird memory problem in PHP. I think something is only allowing an array to be a maximum of 0.25M. It appears the script is only using up to around 6M before it crashes.

Here's the output from xdebug:

[image]

Here's the function it is calling. The result of the sql query is about 800 rows of text.

```
public function getOptions(){
    $sql = "select Opt,
                   Code,
                   Description
            from PCAOptions";

    $result = sqlsrv_query($this->conn,$sql);

    $arrayResult = array();
    echo ini_get('memory_limit'); //this confirms that my memory limit is high enough
    while($orderObject = sqlsrv_fetch_object($result,'PCA_Option')){
        array_push($arrayResult, $orderObject);
    }
    return $arrayResult;
}
```

Comment: nitpick, use `$arrayResult[] = $orderObject;` as it uses less resources. This is indeed strange though.

Comment: There is an overhead induced by the PHP structures to make arrays and objects - not sure how much it costs in this case. But check the actual size of the output from the *mysql* command line tool... sometimes we have some surprises :-)

Comment: What was your memory limit set to?

Comment: You can see in the screenshot the output of the ini_get('memory_limit') -- 1024M

Comment: Try `memory_get_usage(true)` to check how much memory script use.

Comment: @viakondratiuk I tried echoing that after each array_push and it seemed to match up with what xdebug was giving me in the memory column.

Comment: And of course arrays have overhead, you can read http://nikic.github.com/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html

Comment: Almost looks like there's a `ini_set("memory_limit", "256K")` where there should be a `ini_set("memory_limit", "256M")`

Comment: You may have already tried this, but does increasing the `memory_limit`, further, allow the script to complete successfully?

Comment: @prisoner just tried it with 2048M and got the exact same results.

Comment: same numbers reported by xdebug?

Comment: Everything was the same up until step #5 but at that point it was only a difference of about 500 bytes.

Comment: This code is part of some framework? Can you create separate script and try do the same query in it?

Comment: Perhaps when you fetch from `sqlsrv_query` it acquires results from the database, and old results are marked for garbage collection but not actually deleted?

Comment: I checked my xdebug and everything reported correct numbers for me, which makes me think it's more of a config issue. Is there any way you can set the memory within your php.ini file or through .htaccess? Is this happening locally? If so, change your php.ini `memory_limit` and restart httpd.

Comment: I have the memory_limit set in both my php.ini and my .htaccess. This method is part of a class that extends Mage_Shell_Abstract which does check the .htaccess file and call ini_set on php variables in the constructor, but I've stepped through it and confirmed it is setting it to 1024M.

Comment: Can you post that file please, well, the memory relevant stuff.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zDc8H4V0

Comment: Does your httpd not handle parsing of the .htaccess file using `php_value memory_limit 1024M`? Secondly, does the script throw any errors if your don't suppress the `ini_sets` on lines 116 and 122 (remove the `@`'s)?

Comment: also, might be worth checking this question & answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5860101/475125 - apart from that, good luck getting it fixed and if you work it out please be sure to post the solution, I'm puzzled as to whats going on!

Comment: This discussion is growing too long and hard to follow. However it contains good information which should be integrated into the post. Please do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I don't know how or why this worked, but I fixed the problem by commenting out these two lines from my .htaccess file:

```
#    php_value memory_limit 1024M
#    php_value max_execution_time 18000
```

I did this because I noticed phpinfo() was returning different values for these settings in the two columns "master" and "local".

My php.ini had memory_limit=512M and max_execution_time=3000, whereas my .htacces file had the above values. I thought .htaccess would just override whatever was in php.ini but I guess it caused a conflict. Could this be a possible bug in php?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, but is it in apache, mod-php or php it's self? I would [submit it as a bug to php](https://bugs.php.net/) and see what they say.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of steps some PHP distributions, security packages, and web hosts take to prevent users from raising the PHP actual memory limit at runtime via `ini_set`.  The most likely candidate is the [suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.memory_limit) security package.

This older [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161784/cannot-increase-memory-limit-with-ini-set) has a number of other suggestions as well.

Answer (score -2):

When working with 'big' scripts which i know will bypass my server PHP memory limits,
i always set this variable at the beginning of the script. Works all the time.

```
ini_set("memory_limit","32M"); //Script should use up to 32MB of memory
```

Comment: it works all the time, but unless you actually want your scripts to run continues, for days if not weeks or months, you are better of setting a very large value, for example: `set_time_limit(86400); // 24 hours` You wouldn't be the first to lock up a server.

Comment: Answer and comment are off topic. In question is a "memory limit", not a "time limit" problem.