# Problems with encoded array in php

Tags: php, parsing, get

I have problem to parse a get variable which contains an array and send it with jquery ajax.

the array what I send can look as it follows

```
ids%5B%5D   1403172219
ids%5B%5D   1530542001
ids%5B%5D   1582588379
```

but when I try to dump(`$_GET['ids]`) I get null I dumb the hole `$_GET` than looks like

```
ids%5B%5D] => 1530542001
```

**JQuery**

```
function update_category(selected) {
    console.log(cids);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/admin/',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "application/JSON",
        data: {
            ids: cids,
            s_category: selected,
            controller: 'products',
            traditional: true,
            action: 'update_category'
        },
        success: function(data) {
            addAlert('alert-'+data, data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            addAlert('alert-'+data.responseText, data.responseText);
        }
    });
```

**controller**

```
  protected function update_category() {
        print_r($_GET);
        $cat_ids = $_GET['ids'];
        $category = $_GET['s_category'];       
        if(!empty($cat_ids) && !empty($category)){
            $this->model->updateCategory($cat_ids, $category);
        } else {
            echo 'Fähler in der Daten übergabe!';
            exit();
        }              
    }
}
```

on localhost I use PHP 5.4 and I do not face any problems on live Server ubuntu PHP 5.3.10 the error persist

the correct output on localhost

```
Array ( 
[ids] => Array (
    [0] => B6Q09EA#ABD 
    [1] => H4P04EA#ABD 
    ) 
[s_category] => 4
[controller] => products 
[traditional] => true 
[action] => update_category 
)
```

ids are builded like

```
cids = [];
jQuery.each(sData, function(key, value) {
       cids.push(value.value);
});
```

Comment: it will only show last one because it will replace all and equal to last one please change index aur make ids[] as an array

Comment: What is the problem? This behaviour is expected. Please clarify what you want to do. And show us your jquery code.

Comment: Is the character encoding the same on both machines? Also, is this output printing on SO correctly?

Comment: what you mean my meta header?

Comment: Seems your AJAX is sending a JSON encoded string while your PHP is expecting an unencoded GET variable?

Comment: okay but how is possible that this works on windows xampp and under ubuntu server don't. On xampp tho model is getting loaded and query executed

Comment: Can you verify that all data is using UTF-8, you php.ini specifies UTF-8 and your webbrowser shows UTF-8 as ists received header for your page?

Comment: on both of servers the default_charset is uncommented and Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8

Comment: this one makes to get crazy! I don't understand why doesn'twork on ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your live server will probably be an IPv6 enabled host. That means that `[` and `]` (or `%5B` and `%5D`) are reserved characters. `encodeURI`, which is applied to your stringified request string, doesn't, or rather *cannot* encode these chars properly, just as `&` and `=` aren't encoded.
The issue here is the PHP version (or maybe suhosin)  you have installed on your server, I think. I make this assumption based [on this bug report](https://github.com/YOURLS/YOURLS/issues/1439), where one response stated the following:

> I just updated from PHP 5.3 (with suhosin 0.9.33) to PHP 5.5 (without suhosin) and this fixed the issue. I guess some security stuff within suhosin might be the cause for the spinning icon issue I had.
>
> I could switch back to PHP 5.3 and remove the suhosin module to further investigate this, but I think the public interest might not be too high as I seem to be the only reported case with this problem. :-)

verify if your server has suhosin installed, and check your `phpinfo()` on both servers, that should fix it.
Alternatively, you could choose to *not* use jQuery for this, and write your own `XMLHttpRequest`, and add a `encodeURI(stringifiedObject).replace(/%5B/g, '[').replace(/%5D/g,']');` before sending the data.

Some more details on the IPv6 thing: [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FencodeURI#Description)

A temporary workaround/fix might be to fix the request server-side, if you're not willing to ditch jQ:

```
$post = http_get_request_body();//requires http extension
$post = str_replace(
    array('%5B', %5D'),
    array('[',']'),
    $post;
);
```

Then [using `parse_str`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), you can construct the `$_POST` array:

```
parse_str($post, $_POST);
```

That should give you the array you need.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback I will check it Monday. I hope this is the workaround

Comment: my phpinfo on live server shows that I'm on IPv6 I Have been disabling IPv6 support but phpinfo shows the same

Comment: @fefe: and what about suhosin? is that being used? and is it working using `http_get_request_body`, instead of using the flawed `$_POST` array?

Comment: okay I just made an upgrade to php5.4, suhosin is not listed in php info but the problem still persist. Because of the complexity of my jquery ajax I would like to avoid to refactor

Comment: @fefe: on suhosin, you [may want to look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383916/how-to-check-whether-suhosin-is-installed), it needn't always show up in `phpinfo`. The whole idea of this extension is security, so it may be there, but hidden from the `phpinfo`

Comment: than I added [suhosin]
suhosin.simulation = On to my php.ini as I understand this one should make the fix if suhosin extension is activated

Comment: @fefe: Not quite with you there, but have you been able to fix the issue?

Comment: yes thank you for your feedback. After all having configured the Server upgrading packages the problem is solvedand the bug as you suggested was suhosin. Thanks again