# PHP and Apache not uploading and processing large files

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, large-data

When I try to upload a large file (it is a 65MB `.exe`) to my website using an HTML form and PHP the PHP code that processes the uploaded file is not called even though the file is uploaded to the server, when I upload a smaller file it processed normally. No errors are logged in my Apache `ErrorLog` file.

I have changed the following entries in my `php.ini` file (as recommended [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#107406), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263480/upload-max-size-in-php)) and verified that the new values are loaded correctly using `phpinfo()` (after re-staring Apache and rebooting the server), however the problem still persists:

```
memory_limit = -1
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 150M
max_input_time = 10800
max_execution_time = 10800
```

I have also tried setting these values in my `.htaccess` file as well (`AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo Indexes Limit Options=All,MultiViews` is set under `<Directory />`and `<Directory /var/www/>` in the `apache2.conf` file) with the same result:

```
php_value memory_limit -1
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size 150M
php_value max_input_time 10800
php_value max_execution_time 10800
```

The `max_input_time` and `max_execution_time` options are much higher than the time it actually takes to upload the file (30 minutes).

I am running PHP Version 5.5.9 and Apache version 2.4.7 on a server with Ubuntu 14.04 installed.

Code that should process the uploaded file:

```
    if (isset($_POST['sent']))
{
    $_SESSION['successfulupload']=0.1;
    $version=isset($_POST['version']) ? $_POST['version'] : '';
    $required=isset($_POST['required']) ? $_POST['required'] : '';
    $changelog=nl2br(isset($_POST['changelog']) ? $_POST['changelog'] : '');
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $date=date("d/m/y"); 
    $public=isset($_POST['public']) ? $_POST['public'] : '';
    if ($_FILES["program"]["error"]== UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
    {
        $_SESSION['successfulupload']=0.2;
        if ($_FILES["program"]["size"]>0)
        {
            $_SESSION['successfulupload']=0.3;
            $originalname = $_FILES["program"]["name"];
            $fileformat = $ext = end((explode(".", $originalname)));
            $tmp_name = $_FILES["program"]["tmp_name"];
            $name = "vStrips Installer Version " . $version . "." . $fileformat;
            if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/programs/" . $name))
            {
                $_SESSION['successfulupload']=0.4;
                $link="/programs/" . $name;
                $mysql_host = "xxxxx";
                $mysql_database = "vstrips_root";
                $mysql_user = "vstrips_root";
                $mysql_password = "xxxxx";
                $con=mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password,$mysql_database);
                if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                {
                    $_SESSION['error']="Error: Failed to connect to MySQL database.";
                    die("");
                }
                $_SESSION['successfulupload']=0.5;
                $query="INSERT INTO downloads (version, date, required, changelog, link, public)
                        VALUES ('$version', '$date', '$required', '$changelog', '$link', '$public')";
                if (mysqli_query($con, $query))
                {
                    $_SESSION['successfulupload']=1;
                    echo "vStrips uploaded to website.";
                }
                else
                {
                    $_SESSION['error']="Error: " . mysqli_error($con);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION['error']="Error! Failed to move file from temp location.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['error']="Error! File has no content.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['error']="Error! Failed to upload file.";
    }
}
```

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES);` – what does the `error` entry say …?

Comment: I can't access it as the code doesn't get that far - the form is sent to `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`, but the code under `if (isset($_POST['sent']))` is not run.

Comment: Can we see the code within the `if (isset($_POST['sent']))` block?

Comment: Configure PHP to write errors to a logfile as well.

Comment: Sure: done. It will be around 30 minutes until the file uploads and I will check the log.

Comment: Hang on, PHP errors were previously recorded in my Apache `ErrorLog` file - when they were triggered by bad coding. No new errors appeared in this file after uploading the file. Will declaring a specific log file do anything? The value in my `php.ini` was already `log_errors = On`.

Comment: No errors were written to the logfile.

Comment: _“even though the file is uploaded to the server”_ – how did you verify that part?

Comment: I am using AJAX to monitor the file upload progress and the upload gets to 100% each time (I have tried to upload the file 4 times now).

Comment: Server can be configured to use Suhosin patch. Suhosin can disable binary file uploads or can evaluate a script on post upload  for security reasons.
 
You can check those links for more info;
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3384079/3399234

https://suhosin.org/stories/configuration.html#suhosin-upload-disallow-binary
https://suhosin.org/stories/configuration.html#suhosin-upload-remove-binary

https://suhosin.org/stories/configuration.html#suhosin-upload-verification-script

Comment: It doesn't look like it is installed - I used this code to check (negative result): `<?php
if(extension_loaded('suhosin'))
{
echo "EXT Loaded";
}
echo constant("SUHOSIN_PATCH");
?>`

Comment: I've managed to get it working by uploading using [this Java Applet](http://jupload.sourceforge.net/). Someone else reported that they managed to upload the same application using the original upload method (on their 4th attempt), but after that it stopped working.